# Как разбить текст по нескольким инпутам?

Tags: javascript

Есть 3 инпута с ограничением максимальной длины. Как автоматически разбивать вставляемый в первый инпут текст на 3 инпута по 3 знака в каждом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
// Получаем список input
var els__inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input');

var int__maxSimbols = 3; // Максимальное количество символов

// Запускаем перебор всех input
els__inputs.forEach(function (el__input, int__input) {
  el__input.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    if (this.value.length >= int__maxSimbols) {
      var str__value = this.value,
          int__inputLength = els__inputs.length - int__input;
      
      str__value = str__value.substring(0, int__maxSimbols * int__inputLength);
      
      // Разбиваем текст на несколько полей
      for (var i = 0; i < els__inputs.length - int__input; i++) {
        var el__selectElement = els__inputs[int__input + i];
        
        // Обрезаем от общей строки нужное количество символов
        // Алгоритм я расписать не могу, т.к. сам его не очень понимаю :D
        if (el__selectElement.value === '') el__selectElement.value = str__value.substring(int__maxSimbols * i, int__maxSimbols * int__inputLength * (i + 1));
        el__selectElement.value = el__selectElement.value.substring(0, int__maxSimbols);
      };
      
      // Ищем следующий элемент, который нужно фокусировать
      var int__idxNextElement = Math.ceil(str__value.length / int__maxSimbols) - 1 + int__input;
      
      els__inputs[int__idxNextElement].focus();
    };
  });
  // Сделаем ещё переход на предыдущее поле по нажатию Backspace
  el__input.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 8 && el__input.value.length === 0 && int__input !== 0) {
      els__inputs[int__input - 1].focus();
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="text" class="input">
```